# websockets - reject a socket connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) as the socket library for my node.js library.
so my question is, how can I reject a connection if the user doesn't pass the authorization process.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 6969});

wss.on('connection', function(socket){
// if the socket.upgradeReq.headers.cookie doesn't exists, reject the client
})
```

thanks a lot

Comment: [relevant github issue](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/517)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use [`socket.close()`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#websocketclosecode-data) or [`socket.terminate()`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#websocketterminate) to close the connection.

Answer (score 4):

it is `socket.disconnect()` for the current version